# Place 2 buttons next to each other in Bootstrap Div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Looking to have a title, subtitle and then two boxes close together and next to each other in the final third div.

Struggling  to get 2 buttons to align in the centre next to each other. Seems fine in certain widths, but flows onto the next line at full width

```
        <div class="button-box">
        <div class="myoffer3 col-lg-6">
                <a href="mylink.php" class="btn btn-info" role="button">About Us</a>
            </div>
        <div class="myoffer4 col-lg-6">
                <a href="mylink.php" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Our Products</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My CSS

```
.myoffer3 {
display: inline;
padding:20px;
}
.myoffer4 {
 display: inline;
 padding: 0 20px;

 }
 .button-box {
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
 }
```

Comment: can you paster your full html?

Comment: It already inline, What is your expectation?

Comment: col-lg-6-push-2 and pull-2 in myoffer3/4, seems to have done it. Not sure if that is the official way though

Comment: Now i understand what you mean. Here the official way to fix that.

Answer (score 10):

I already knew what you mean.
Here is the correct way to fix.

HTML

```
  <div class="button-box col-lg-12">
            <a href="mylink.php" class="btn btn-info" role="button">About Us</a>
            <a href="mylink.php" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Our Products</a>
   </div>
```

CSS

```
.button-box {
   text-align:center;
   margin-top:20px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kw4wpt4m/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use boostrap class `text-center`

Use below like this,

```
<div class="button-box">
        <div class="myoffer3 col-lg-6">
                <a href="mylink.php" class="btn btn-info text-center" role="button">About Us</a>
            </div>
        <div class="myoffer4 col-lg-6">
                <a href="mylink.php" class="btn btn-info text-center" role="button">Our Products</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: i really don't understand what the different?

Comment: what didn't you understand?

Comment: the person who ask the question. There is no different.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" role="button">About Us</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Our Products</a>
</div>
```

This works for me, the buttons are next to each other

Comment: yeay spongebob !

Answer (score 0):

Simplest Way to do in Bootstrap 4 and above / Two Button Inline.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
 <button class="btn btn-primary">Download</button><button class="btn btn-primary ml-3">Print Confirmation</button>
</body>

</html>
```